# php header function working

Tags: php, refresh

I have written the following code to refresh page and print the random number but i don`t understand its logic.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Refresh</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Random refresh</h1>

<p>page is refreshed every 5 seconds </p>

<br> </br>

<p>Radom number between 10 to 100 is : 

<?php  

echo(rand(10,100));
header("Refresh: 5; url=randomRefresh.php");  

?>

</p>


</body>
</html>
```

According to my knowledge php is a server side language so code inside the php block should be executed once.

So how does header function refresh/redirect the page ?

does the output html page of php file use implicit Ajax request ?

what is happening under the hood ?

Comment: how its possible that you have written code, without understanding the logic, please provide honest justification.

Comment: What you don't understand? **PHP** execution? The code would first print those **HTML**, then `echo` and then the refresh. What is wrong?

Comment: You can check about php header function http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: You can use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=randomRefresh.php" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"Refresh: 5; url=randomRefresh.php"` function is executed browser side. The php `headers()` function are executed server-side

`header()` in PHP merely sets an additional or existing header that is sent to the client's browser upon page load but `Refresh: 5; url=randomRefresh.php` is interpreted by the client's browser to refresh the page after 5 seconds. Other examples of headers are like `status` that can be 200, 301, 302, 404.

Answer (score 0):

It is executed once as the page is load, but than there is a code as

```
header("Refresh: 5; url=randomRefresh.php");
```

which reloads the page after 5 seconds and than again that php block is executed on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=randomRefresh.php" />`

```
header("Refresh: 5; url=randomRefresh.php");
```

will through error if anything printed in the page before it being call.

So if your page name is `refresh_page_every_5_second.php` then your code will be look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Refresh</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=refresh_page_every_5_second.php" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Random refresh</h1>
<p>page is refreshed every 2 seconds </p>
<br> </br>
<p>Radom number between 10 to 100 is : 
<?php  
echo(rand(10,100));
//("Refresh: 5; url=randomRefresh.php");  
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```